# Why sudden change in reputation rank (from 97% to 0.97%)?

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-leagues

On my [profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558639/fearless-fool), I notice that my reputation is now "top 0.97% overall".  Since it was 97% a few weeks ago, I suspect a bug.

Comment: That's actually an *increase* in rank. Top 97% means you only have 3% of users below you.

Comment: To expand off what Glorfindel said, if it *was* displaying 97% before, that would have been the bug. I don't believe that system is even designed to display percentages that high. It should just not display anything if you don't have a sufficiently good percentage in any leaderboard.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot maybe from a few weeks ago showing the 97%?

Comment: I believe you (collectively) are correct.  I think what happened was I went from being > top 1% to < 1% and only then noticed the change.  I'd be happy to delete this question...

Answer (score 2):

This is your overall ranking in the Reputation League. Clicking the percentage leads to [this](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/558639#558639) where you'll see more details.

Being in the top 0.97% means that you're in the top 100000 users of Stack Overflow or so (12 million users, so 1% is 120000).

Comment: Actually false.  The total number of users is calculated based on those users that are over 200+ rep (or 599,767) users.  5,812 / 599,767 = ~0.97%.  5,812 / 11,886,978 = ~0.0049%